# Birds being off topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

This question has been closed twice.. Poultry is on topic... what about pet birds?

[birds](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birds)

https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birds

[Why should I not give water or food to a wounded bird?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/140/why-should-i-not-give-a-wounded-bird-water)

Comment: On topic... there were some issues with the post to start off but those have been corrected.

Comment: @Lix yes it was corrected, reopened, answered and them closed again

Comment: Reopen vote posted.

Comment: @AnkitSharma thnx I feel sorry for the OP.. twice closed ! Good it is happening now.. it's good to sort these things out hey

Comment: Good grief, I should hope not! As an aside, just saw a hummingbird in the desert...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why it got closed the second time. After your edit, it totally works as an on topic question.  I know many people with pet birds who could find themselves in a situation where they would want to know this information!

I think birds are totally on topic here, because they can be pets just like any other animal we have had questions about. I suspect it got closed the first time for not being a pet related question, just a general avian related query but since your edit, it should be fine, and I believe it has gotten reopened.

Remember, the wording has been changed to "on hold" for good reason - closure isn't always intended to be permanent, but might just be a way of saying something is wrong with the post. In this case, I think your edit solved the problem. :)

Comment: That's why i posted this question http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/203/why-to-post-close-vote-so-soon because here we are closing question too sonn and on/off topic doesn't seems to be clear